# debugging pycharm __gettattr__

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, pycharm, getattr

I have a problem with debugging in PyCharm (maybe this problem is observable in other IDEs too):

If you take the following code:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg1 = 'abc'
        self.arg2 = 'def'
        self.some_other_class = SomeOtherClass()
        return

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(item)
        if callable(getattr(self.some_other_class, 'blabla')):
            abc = 123
        return

x = Test1()
```

and my breakpoint is at `self.arg1 = 'abc'`, the following happens:

Only in debugging mode there is a lookup for the instance variable `__len__`, which is not found --> then `__getattr__`
is called. 
(I see this because of the `print(item)`-Statement in `__getattr__`). Then `self.some_other_class` is looked up.
This is not found: recursively dive into `__getattr__` and so on and so on until RecursionError occurs.

Is there anything I can do against this behavior, because I need to debug?

Comment: FWIW you can still debug, this recursion error does not stop the debugging session

Comment: Yes, but the debugging behaves very strange (e.g. the pointer to the code-line is not correct anymore) and sometimes i get a real stackoverflow error from pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Either define a `__len__` method or check whether `'some_other_class'` is present in `self.__dict__.keys()`.

---

**Long answer:**

The recursion occurs when

1. you try to get a non-existent attribute from a class *and*
2. you have a `__getattr__` method in that class *and*
3. within the `__getattr__` method you try to get a non-existent attribute from the same class

The recursion error can for example be obtained in the following example, where `self.some_other_class` is not defined:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg1 = 'abc'
        self.arg2 = 'def'
        return

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(item)
        self.some_other_class
        return

x = Test1()
x.test
```

When x.test is called, the `__getattr__` method is called, which calls `self.some_other_class`, which again calls the `__getattr__` method, which again calls `self.some_other_class`, etc.

Of course in your case the `self.some_other_class` is defined, and then there is no recursion:

```
class SomeOtherClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg1 = 'abc'
        self.arg2 = 'def'
        self.some_other_class = SomeOtherClass
        return

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print(item)
        self.some_other_class
        return

x = Test1()
x.test
```

However, in the debug mode of PyCharm probably the `__len__` attribute of the class is called after manually running a line in the file. In the example this means that after the first two lines in the `Test1.__init__` method `self.some_other_class` is not defined yet, and also `Test1.__len__` is not defined. Therefore calling the `__len__` attribute will result in the recursion error.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Define the `__len__` method:

   ```
   class Test1:
       ...
       def __len__(self):
           return 1
   ```
2. Check in `__getattr__` whether the passed item is present in the class:

   ```
   class Test1:
       ...
       def __getattr__(self, item):
           print(item)
           if 'some_other_class' in self.__dict__:
               if hasattr(self.some_other_class, 'blabla')):
                   abc = 123
               return
   ```

   Note that just calling `getattr(self.some_other_class, 'blabla')` or `hasattr(self.some_other_class, 'blabla')` without the check in `self.__dict__` also triggers the `__getattr__` method.

Comment: `if 'some_other_class' in self.__dict__.keys()` -> `if 'some_other_class' in self.__dict__` or even `if 'some_other_class' in vars(self)`

Comment: Thanks! Corrected it.